# Focusing the scrollbar in a specific text in a multiline textbox

Tags: vb.net, textbox, focus, scrollbar, multiline

I have a multiline textbox that contains very long text in it.
How can I scroll the scrollbar to the line with specific text in a textbox?
Im a newbie and using vb.net.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This may be a duplicate post, [Caret position in textarea, in characters from the start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-cursor-position-in-textarea) - except in this one they are just getting the position, not setting it.

Comment: I'm very surprised that that the OP accepted this answer, since the linked question is about Javascript, not vb.net.

Comment: Can you solve the OPs question with a vb.net solution? He admitted his inexperience so perhaps he didn't know it would be a Javascript solution.